# No output from heob in a Qt application using Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, memory-leak-detector

I would like to use heob to check my app for memory leaks. This is what i tried: I opened the project "analogclock" from the examples collection in qtcreator. After that i have chosen "Analyze" and "Heob" from the drop down menu. After choosing the heob path and a click on the ok button, the application starts and a console window "heob32" is displayed. But now nothing happens. Just the word "kill" is displayed in the console window. I can´t see any output and if i close the analogclock app i get the message: "heob: cannot create target process". Can anyone help me further to get useful output from heob?

Comment: It's possible that your Antivirus is interfering with heob.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using and what heob did you install?
You need to download and install heob separately from Creator. Creator just installs a link without heob itself. Have you done this? Are you really running on a 32-bit system (there is a heob64 in case you are using a modern OS).
Did you configure your heob installation in Qt Creator correctly?
Can you run heob from the commandline with reasonable behaviour?